# Apache Spark Pivot Query Stuck (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have simple data as:

```
+--------------------+-----------------+-----+
|     timebucket_start|               user| hits|
+--------------------+-----------------+-----+
|[2017-12-30 01:02...|              Messi|    2|
|[2017-12-30 01:28...|             Jordan|    9|
|[2017-12-30 11:12...|             Jordan|  462|
+--------------------+-----------------+-----+
```

I am trying to pivot it such that I get the counts of each user for each of the time buckets,

So, my query in PySaprk is (using dataframes):

```
user_time_matrix = df.groupBy('timebucket_start').pivot("user").sum('hits')
```

Now, this query just keeps running all the time. I tried it with a scaled cluster too, doubling my cluster size, but then also same issue.

Is the query wrong? Can it be optimized, why can't spark finish it?

Comment: Where is the column 'count'?

Comment: @pissall sorry.. it should be hits ..it is hits in the actual query..will correct it in the question

Comment: What is the output from `df.select("user").distinct().count()`?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same thing but you can try :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
user_time_matrix = df.groupBy('timebucket_start').pivot("user").agg(F.sum('hits'))
```

Let me know if there is any error or infinite loop. Also when you use this code, the users will become the columns link :

Input :

```
+----+----------+------+
|hits|      time|  user|
+----+----------+------+
|   2|2017-12-30| Messi|
|   3|2017-12-30|Jordan|
| 462|2017-12-30|Jordan|
|   2|2017-12-31| Messi|
|   2|2017-12-31| Messi|
+----+----------+------+
```

Output:

```
+----------+------+-----+                                                       
|      time|Jordan|Messi|
+----------+------+-----+
|2017-12-31|  null|    4|
|2017-12-30|   465|    2|
+----------+------+-----+
```

I would recommend:

```
user_time_matrix = df.groupBy('timebucket_start', 'user').sum('hits')
```

Output :

```
+----------+------+---------+
|      time|  user|sum(hits)|
+----------+------+---------+
|2017-12-31| Messi|        4|
|2017-12-30|Jordan|      465|
|2017-12-30| Messi|        2|
+----------+------+---------+
```

Comment: thanks, but I get the error u"cannot resolve '`user`' given input columns:  .. but the input is exactly the dataframe as I showed in the question...

Comment: Why is your 'timebucket_start' a list object? Are there more than one elements in it?

Comment: i got i through df = df.groupBy(window(tf["timebucket_start"], "2 minutes"), 'user').count() and then did df.select (
    'window.start',
    'user',
    'count'
) and renamed the columns .. so yes it was a list earlier but then I selected just the first element